# NetCDF Big data

Tags: python, netcdf, bigdata

I need to read in large (+15GB) NetCDF files into a program, which holds a 3D variable (etc Time as the record dimension, and the data is latitudes by longitudes).

I'm processing the data in a 3 level nested loop (checking each block of the NetCDF if it passes a certain criteria. For example;

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset                   
import numpy as np

File = Dataset('Somebigfile.nc', 'r')
Data = File.variables['Wind'][:]

Getdimensions = np.shape(Data)
Time = Getdimensions[0]
Latdim  = Getdimensions[1]
Longdim = Getdimensions[2]

for t in range(0,Time):
    for i in range(0,Latdim):
        for j in range(0,Longdim):

            if Data[t,i,j] > Somethreshold:
                #Do something
```

Is there anyway I can read in the NetCDF file one time record at a time? Reducing the memory usage hugely. Any help hugely appreciated.

I know of NCO operators but would prefer not to use these methods to break up files before using the script.

Comment: Solved myself; use Data = File.variables['Wind'][:] inside the loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you've already settled on a solution but I'll throw out a much more elegant and vectorized (likely faster) solution that uses `xarray` and `dask`. Your nested for loop is going to be very inefficient. Combining `xarray` and `dask`, you can work on the data in your file incrementally in a semi-vectorized manor.

Since your `Do something` step isn't all that specific, you'll have to extrapolate from my example.

```
import xarray as xr

# xarray will open your file but doesn't load in any data until you ask for it
# dask handles the chunking and memory management for you
# chunk size can be optimized for your specific dataset.
ds = xr.open_dataset('Somebigfile.nc', chunks={'time': 100})

# mask out values below the threshold
da_thresh = ds['Wind'].where(ds['Wind'] > Somethreshold)

# Now just operate on the values greater than your threshold
do_something(da_thresh)
```

Xarray/Dask docs: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/dask.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My solution isn't too bad as the reading of the netcdf file happens at every timestep (first level of the loop, not the third most embedded leve); the processing inside the loop takes ~30 seconds anyway so an extra head of 1s of reading from disk vs memory isn't too painful. Great suggestion though, looks much more efficient.